# Does GDI+ have standard image encoder CLSIDs?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+, clsid

The GDI+ [`Image::Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535407(v=vs.85).aspx) method requires a CLSID parameter to specify the encoder to use. The documentation points to [some sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533843(v=vs.85).aspx) for getting the encoder associated with a particular MIME type, such as image/jpeg or image/png. However I'm balking at the thought of copying a half-page function just to support a 1-line debugging aid where I save an intermediate result out to disk.

Shouldn't there be a list of standard CLSIDs for the standard encoders? Where would I find such a list? I haven't been able to find one by searching Microsoft's include files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't one.  I think they intended the codec list to be extensible and support plugins, but never got around to it.  Given that they haven't made any changes to GDI+ in quite some time, they likely won't anytime soon. You could probably get away with generating your own hard coded list based on an enumeration of Gdiplus::GetImageEncoders.

That is:

```
image/bmp  : {557cf400-1a04-11d3-9a73-0000f81ef32e}
image/jpeg : {557cf401-1a04-11d3-9a73-0000f81ef32e} 
image/gif  : {557cf402-1a04-11d3-9a73-0000f81ef32e} 
image/tiff : {557cf405-1a04-11d3-9a73-0000f81ef32e}
image/png  : {557cf406-1a04-11d3-9a73-0000f81ef32e}
```

Here's the function I routinely cut&paste between projects for getting at the CLSID of the encoder. You could modify it to be a table lookup.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

HRESULT GetGdiplusEncoderClsid(const std::wstring& format, GUID* pGuid)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    UINT  nEncoders = 0;          // number of image encoders
    UINT  nSize = 0;              // size of the image encoder array in bytes
    std::vector<BYTE> spData;
    Gdiplus::ImageCodecInfo* pImageCodecInfo = NULL;
    Gdiplus::Status status;
    bool found = false;

    if (format.empty() || !pGuid)
    {
        hr = E_INVALIDARG;
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        *pGuid = GUID_NULL;
        status = Gdiplus::GetImageEncodersSize(&nEncoders, &nSize);

        if ((status != Gdiplus::Ok) || (nSize == 0))
        {
            hr = E_FAIL;
        }
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {

        spData.resize(nSize);
        pImageCodecInfo = (Gdiplus::ImageCodecInfo*)&spData.front();
        status = Gdiplus::GetImageEncoders(nEncoders, nSize, pImageCodecInfo);

        if (status != Gdiplus::Ok)
        {
            hr = E_FAIL;
        }
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        for (UINT j = 0; j < nEncoders && !found; j++)
        {
            if (pImageCodecInfo[j].MimeType == format)
            {
                *pGuid = pImageCodecInfo[j].Clsid;
                found = true;
            }
        }

        hr = found ? S_OK : E_FAIL;
    }

    return hr;
}


int main()
{
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    GUID guidBmp = {};
    GUID guidJpeg = {};
    GUID guidGif = {};
    GUID guidTiff = {};
    GUID guidPng = {};

    GetGdiplusEncoderClsid(L"image/bmp", &guidBmp);
    GetGdiplusEncoderClsid(L"image/jpeg", &guidJpeg);
    GetGdiplusEncoderClsid(L"image/gif", &guidGif);
    GetGdiplusEncoderClsid(L"image/tiff", &guidTiff);
    GetGdiplusEncoderClsid(L"image/png", &guidPng);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: These CLSIDs do not exist in registry. The only codec CLSIDs I could find that actually exist in the Registry turned out to be for Windows Imaging Component (WIC) codecs, rather than GDI+ codecs. Does GDI+'s Image::Save() map the encoder CLSID it receives to an actual encoder using an hard-coded list?

Comment: Why does it matter if the GUIDs are in the registry?

Comment: If they were in the registry's CLSID key, it would mean they can be used from outside of GDI+ like ordinary COM classes (that's what a CLSID means, after all). But more importantly I'd have expected a key referencing all codecs, where codecs can be added for extensibility. Unfortunately it seems GDI+ can't be extended with new codecs, only WIC can.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to write a PNG, this appears to work:

```
// image/png  : {557cf406-1a04-11d3-9a73-0000f81ef32e}
const CLSID pngEncoderClsId = { 0x557cf406, 0x1a04, 0x11d3,{ 0x9a,0x73,0x00,0x00,0xf8,0x1e,0xf3,0x2e } }; 
stat = image->Save(L"test.png", &pngEncoderClsId, NULL);
```

Note the reformatting of the hex values.

From:
[How to initialize a constant CLSID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975918/how-to-initialize-a-constant-clsid)

Comment: GetEncoderClsid(L"image/png", ...) didn't work for some reason, but the this worked just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You will probably want to use `ImageCodecInfo` with `GetImageEncodersSize()` and `GetImageEncoders()` I'm not aware of any easier way.

EDIT: If you know specifically what you want and damn all the rest you can get away with doing something like this ...

```
CLSID pngClsid;
GetEncoderClsid("image/png", &pngClsid);
image.Save("imagename.png", &pngClsid, NULL);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I tried to do, but `GetEncoderClsid` isn't part of GDI+ - you have to copy it from the documentation.