# How to save 1 BPP, 4 BPP and 8BPP image

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

Can any one let me know how to save 1BPP ,  4BPP and 8BPP as Bitmap. I have bits in the image, width and height.

Please let me know how to save that as bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows and C++, the easiest way is [Gdiplus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  Here's some pseudo code.

```
Gdiplus::Bitmap* pBmp = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(width, height, pixelformat);
pBmp->SetPalette(...); // initialize palette for 8bpp formats and less
pBmp->LockBits(...); // acquire the bitmap buffer

// copy your binary image data into the buffer

pBmp->UnlockBits(...); // return the buffer

pBmp->Save(filename, &clsidBMP, NULL);

delete pBmp;
```

You can get a list of pixel formats defined by GDI plus [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534420%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Most of what you need is defined by the [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534420%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) class, which inherits from the Image class, which defines the [Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535407%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) method.

The encoder clsid, required by the "save" method is a bit tricky to get.  But see my posting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345803/does-gdi-have-standard-image-encoder-clsids/5346026#5346026) on how to acquire this value.

Answer (score 0):

```
ATL::CImage* image_ = new CImage();
image_ -> Create( rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, 32 );

...
image_ -> Save( filename );
delete image_;
```

Change to parameter in Create() appropriately.