# How to initialize a constant CLSID

Tags: c++, visual-studio, com, uuid

A class ID (GUID) is generally specified with a sequence of hex numbers separated by dashes, e.g. `{557cf406-1a04-11d3-9a73-0000f81ef32e}`. This is not a literal that can be used to initialize a CLSID structure directly.

I've discovered two ways to initialize the structure, but they're both kind of awkward. The first doesn't allow it to be declared `const` and must be done at run time, while the second requires extensive reformatting of the hex constants.

```
CLSID clsid1;
CLSIDFromString(CComBSTR("{557cf406-1a04-11d3-9a73-0000f81ef32e}"), &clsid1);

const CLSID clsid2 = { 0x557cf406, 0x1a04, 0x11d3, { 0x9a,0x73,0x00,0x00,0xf8,0x1e,0xf3,0x2e } };
```

I know that Visual Studio can generate one automatically if you have a type that's associated with a UUID, using the [`__uuidof` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zaah6a61.aspx). Is there a way to do it if you only have the hex string?

Comment: Ahem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345803/does-gdi-have-standard-image-encoder-clsids

Comment: You could always use a factory function that calls `CLSIDFromString` - something like `const CLSID clsid1 = GUIDFactoryFunc("{557cf406-1a04-11d3-9a73-0000f81ef32e}")`

Comment: @i_am_jorf why do you think I'm asking the question?  I need to use the answer from that question in a new program, and the code I wrote back then is a job ago and no longer available for reference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Static `CLSID` initialization from string (no runtime conversion helper needed):

```
class __declspec(uuid("{557cf406-1a04-11d3-9a73-0000f81ef32e}")) Foo;
static const CLSID CLSID_Foo = __uuidof(Foo);       
// ...
CComPtr<IUnknown> pUnknown;
pUnknown.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_Foo);
```

or simply direct use of `__uuidof` (compiler will treat the GUID value as a constant and generate minimal necessary code):

```
class __declspec(uuid("{557cf406-1a04-11d3-9a73-0000f81ef32e}")) Foo;
// ...
CComPtr<IUnknown> pUnknown;
pUnknown.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(Foo));
```

It is not anything special: for example when type libraries are [`#import`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6)ed, the same method is used to attach `CLSID`s to coclass based types, and then additional `CLSID_xxx` identifiers might be generated if [additionally requested](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xybakhaa).

Comment: A good one. Could also use some macro to make it a one-liner.

Comment: There is no need actually to define `CLSID_Foo` because `__uuidof(Foo)` can be used directly (making it already a one-liner).

Comment: I think the OP wants a `const CLSID`, so I mentioned the macro.

Answer (score 2):

Use a helper function to create the GUID.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <atlbase.h>

template<class S>
CLSID CreateGUID(const S& hexString)
{
    CLSID clsid;
    CLSIDFromString(CComBSTR(hexString), &clsid);

    return clsid;
}

int main()
{
    const CLSID clsid1 = CreateGUID("{557cf406-1a04-11d3-9a73-0000f81ef32e}");
    const CLSID clsid2 = CreateGUID(L"{557cf406-1a04-11d3-9a73-0000f81ef32e}");
}
```