# How to construct a GDI+ Bitmap object from a Device-Dependent HBITMAP

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+, gdi, color-palette

I want to use GDI+ method [`Image::Save()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535407) to save a [DDB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183561) to a file in the following scenario:

```
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, 200, 200) ;

...

//hBitmap is a DDB so I need to pass an HPALETTE
Gdiplus::Bitmap(hBitmap,  ???HPALETTE???  ).Save(L"file.png", ...) ;
```

The problem is that [`Bitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536314) constructor asks for an `HPALETTE` when the bitmap is not a device-independent bitmap.

Where do I get the necessary HPALETTE from?

---

**FOLLOWUP:**
One of the answers suggests passing NULL as the `HPALETTE` parameter.
Here is a working example that does so. The result is a purely black and white image where all colors are lost.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>

int main(){
    using namespace Gdiplus ;

    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput ;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken ;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL) ;

    CLSID pngEncoder = {0x557cf406, 0x1a04, 0x11d3, {0x9a, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xf8, 0x1e, 0xf3, 0x2e} } ;

    HDC dcHndl = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL) ;

    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcHndl, 200, 200) ;

    SelectObject(dcHndl, hBitmap) ;

    BitBlt(dcHndl, 0,0, 200,200, GetDC(NULL), 0,0, SRCCOPY|CAPTUREBLT) ;

    Bitmap(hBitmap, NULL).Save(L"file.png", &pngEncoder) ;
}
```

Comment: The code in your followup section is wrong, it has nothing to do with Gdi+. You should declare `HDC hdc = GetDC(0)` then use `CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 200, 200)`. Use the same `hdc` in `BitBlt`. Pass `NULL` for palette as suggested. Don't forget cleanup for Gdi handles!

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, can you post an answer? so it's more clear what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First (and this is unrelated to your main question):

When creating a bitmap for screen shot, don't use a memory dc because that creates a monochrome bitmap. That's the main reason you are getting a black and white image (on my computer I just get a black image).

Don't use `GetDC(0)` inside another function. Every call to `GetDC` match have a matching `ReleaseDC` to avoid resource leak.

After calling `BitBlt` it is good practice to select `hbitmap` out of `dc` because you are basically finished drawing on dc.

The following code will work on Windows 10

```
int w = 800;
int h = 600;

HDC hdc = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
HBITMAP hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, w, h);
HBITMAP oldbmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memdc, hbitmap);
BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, w, h, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT);
SelectObject(memdc, oldbmp);

Bitmap(hbitmap, NULL).Save(filename, &pngEncoder);

DeleteObject(hbitmap);
DeleteDC(memdc);
ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP, hdc);
```

Back to your question regarding the documentation:

> Type: HPALETTE
>   Handle to a GDI palette used to define the bitmap colors if hbm is not a device-independent bitmap (DIB).

In addition,

> Do not pass to the Bitmap::FromHBITMAP method a GDI bitmap or a GDI palette that is currently (or was previously) selected into a device context.

The code I posted obeys only one rule, that GDI bitmap is not currently selected in to a device context (but it was previously selected).

The documentation may apply to older versions of Windows. As far as I can see MFC's `CImage` class does not follow all these rules. New computer displays are all 24 or 32 bit, I don't know how you would get a palette for it.

To follow the documentation to the letter, you can convert DDB to DIB section, using `CreateDIBSection` and `GetDIBits`. Use the new DIB section `hbitmap_dib` in `Bitmap::FromHBITMAP`. This will satisfy all of the conditions: `hbitmap` is dib, it is not (and was not) selected in to a device context.

Or, `Gdiplus::Bitmap` has another method `Bitmap::FromBITMAPINFO`. If there is no palette, you can use this code instead:

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
HBITMAP hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, w, h);
HBITMAP oldbmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memdc, hbitmap);
BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, 800, 600, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT);
SelectObject(memdc, oldbmp);

BITMAP bm;
GetObject(hbitmap, sizeof(bm), &bm);
int size = ((bm.bmWidth * bm.bmBitsPixel + 31) / 32) * 4 * bm.bmHeight;
BITMAPINFO info{ sizeof(info), bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, 1, bm.bmBitsPixel, BI_RGB, size };
std::vector<char> bits(size);
GetDIBits(memdc, hbitmap, 0, bm.bmHeight, &bits[0], &info, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

Bitmap *bitmap = Bitmap::FromBITMAPINFO(&info, &bits[0]);
bitmap->Save(filename, &pngEncoder);
delete bitmap;

DeleteObject(hbitmap);
DeleteDC(memdc);
ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP, hdc);
```

Comment: The value of `HWND_DESKTOP` is `(HWND)0`, so doing `GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP)` is the same as `GetDC(0)`

Answer (score 1):

As [CreateCompatibleBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183488(v=vs.85).aspx) remarks sate if you are dealing with color bitmaps we can also assume that `hDC` is a nonmemory device context (because memory device context will only create monochrome bitmaps) and the color palette used by this bitmap is the same color palette used by this device context. You can query it using `GetCurrentObject` method. However remarks to [`Bitmap.Bitmap(HBITMAP, HPALETTE)` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536314(v=vs.85).aspx) state:

> Do not pass to the GDI+ Bitmap::Bitmap constructor a GDI bitmap or a GDI palette that is currently (or was previously) selected into a device context.

So you can not used current device context palette directly and need to create a copy of it instead.

```
/// <returns>
/// Handle to palette currently selected into device context without granting ownership.
/// </returns>
_Check_return_ ::HPALETTE
Fetch_CurrentPalette(_In_ ::HDC const h_dc)
{
    assert(h_dc);
    ::HGDIOBJ const h_palette_object{::GetCurrentObject(h_dc, OBJ_PAL)}; // not owned
    assert(h_palette_object);
    assert(OBJ_PAL == ::GetObjectType(h_palette_object));
    //  Perform unchecked conversion of generic GDI object descriptor to GDI palette descriptor.
    ::HPALETTE h_current_palette{}; // not owned
    {
        static_assert(sizeof(h_palette_object) == sizeof(h_current_palette), "wat");
        ::memcpy
        (
            ::std::addressof(h_current_palette)
        ,   ::std::addressof(h_palette_object)
        ,   sizeof(h_current_palette)
        );
    }
    return(h_current_palette);
}

/// <returns>
/// Handle to palette copy with granting ownership.
/// </returns>
_Check_return_ ::HPALETTE
Make_PaletteCopy(_In_ ::HPALETTE const h_palette)
{
    assert(h_palette);
    ::UINT const first_entry_index{};
    ::UINT entries_count{};
    ::LPPALETTEENTRY p_entries{};
    //  Figure out how many entries palette contains.
    entries_count = ::GetPaletteEntries(h_palette, first_entry_index, entries_count, p_entries);
    assert(1 < entries_count);
    assert(entries_count <= ::std::numeric_limits< decltype(LOGPALETTE::palNumEntries) >::max());
    //  This buffer will hold palette description which contains first PALETTEENTRY as last field.
    //  followed by the rest of PALETTEENTRY items.
    ::std::unique_ptr< ::std::uint8_t[] > const p_buffer
    {
        new ::std::uint8_t[sizeof(::LOGPALETTE) + (sizeof(::PALETTEENTRY) * (entries_count - 1u))]
    };
    //  Perform unchecked conversion of buffer pointer to palette description pointer.
    ::LOGPALETTE * p_description{};
    {
        ::std::uint8_t * const p_buffer_bytes{p_buffer.get()};
        static_assert(sizeof(p_buffer_bytes) == sizeof(p_description), "wat");
        ::memcpy
        (
            ::std::addressof(p_description)
        ,   ::std::addressof(p_buffer_bytes)
        ,   sizeof(p_description)
        );
    }
    //  Copy palette entries into buffer.
    p_entries = static_cast< ::LPPALETTEENTRY >(p_description->palPalEntry);
    ::UINT const copied_entries_count
    {
        ::GetPaletteEntries(h_palette, first_entry_index, entries_count, p_entries)
    };
    assert(copied_entries_count == entries_count);
    //  Create palette copy.
    p_description->palVersion = 0x300; // magic
    p_description->palNumEntries = static_cast< ::WORD >(copied_entries_count);
    ::HPALETTE const h_copied_palette{::CreatePalette(p_description)}; // owned
    assert(h_copied_palette);
    return(h_copied_palette);
}



::HPALETTE const hPal{Make_PaletteCopy(Fetch_CurrentPalette(hDC))}; // owned
assert(hPal);
::HBITMAP const hBitmap{::CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, 200, 200)}; // owned
assert(hBitmap);
{
    ::Gdiplus::Bitmap bmp{hBitmap, hPal};
    assert(::Gdiplus::Status::Ok == bmp.GetLastStatus());
    //  Do something...
}
//  Delete palette and bitmap after GDI+ bitmap object went out of scope.
if(FALSE == ::DeleteObject(hPal))
{
    assert(false);
}
if(FALSE == ::DeleteObject(hBitmap))
{
    assert(false);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can pass NULL. Sample code below.

```
int main()
{
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
    GUID encoder = {};

    GetGdiplusEncoderClsid(L"image/png", &encoder); // https://stackoverflow.com/a/5346026/104458

    HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);

    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 200, 200);

    Bitmap bmp(hBitmap, NULL);

    bmp.Save(L"File.png", &encoder);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This would break the [API contract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536314(v=vs.85).aspx). The parameter `hpal` is **not optional** in this case: _Handle to a GDI palette used to define the bitmap colors if hbm is not a device-independent bitmap (DIB)._

Comment: I get a completely black 200x200 PNG image file with that code (copy-pasted exactly).

Comment: What did you expect? The bitmap created by CreateCompatibleBitmap has no content.

Comment: @selbie, sorry, I didn't notice that at first. I updated the my question with a working example.

Comment: `NULL` is fine for `hpal` if there is no palette to speak of. In your follow up question you are probably working with 32bit screen resolution. You can't even make a palette for that.

Comment: I get confused about dib versus dib section, I don't know what the documentation means exactly. `FromHBITMAP(hbitmap, NULL)` seems to work fine for high color DDB. Maybe the documentation relates to older Window versions.