# How to get a bitmap from a hdc?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

I can load a `hbitmap` into a hdc like this:

```
        Gdiplus::Color Color{ 255, 255, 255 };
        hBitmap = NULL;
        Gdiplus::Bitmap* bitmap = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromFile(L"home.png", false);
        if (bitmap)
        {
            bitmap->GetHBITMAP(Color, &hBitmap);
            delete bitmap;
        }

        BITMAP bm;
        GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(bm), &bm);
        HDC hDCMem = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
        HBITMAP hBitmapOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hDCMem, hBitmap);
```

How could I do the reverse, getting back a bitmap loaded into a specific `hdc`?

I would need first, retrieve the `hbitmap` and then the `bitmap` from it? How?

Comment: Related: [How to construct a GDI+ Bitmap object from a Device-Dependent HBITMAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45319996/), [How to Create a Gdiplus::Bitmap from an HBITMAP, retaining the alpha channel information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335273/)

Comment: [GetCurrentObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getcurrentobject) with `OBJ_BITMAP`

Comment: @dialer nice, I never knew about that function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GetCurrentObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getcurrentobject) to access the `HBITMAP` (and `HPALETTE`) currently selected into an `HDC`.

Alternatively, you can create a new `HBITMAP` of desired dimension and color depth, `SelectObject()` it into a new memory `HDC`, and then `BitBlt()`/`StretchBlt()` the source `HDC` into it.

Either way, once you have an `HBITMAP`, you can create a new GDI+ `Bitmap` from it using the [`Bitmap(HBITMAP, HPALETTE)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusheaders/nf-gdiplusheaders-bitmap-bitmap(hbitmap_hpalette)) constructor or [`Bitmap::FromHBITMAP()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusheaders/nf-gdiplusheaders-bitmap-fromhbitmap) method.

Comment: You could also `SelectObject` a different bitmap, which will return the existing bitmap (and unlink it from the HDC, removing most limits on what you're allowed to do with the bitmap)

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, I thought of that, but that is a potentially destructive operation, depending on where the `HDC` is coming from. You would typically have to remember to restore the old bitmap when finished using it, and hope your code doesn't crash before then.

Comment: Well, you can (and should) select the original bitmap back in the way you found it.  But you could have read from the bitmap before doing so.  Of course, that simply changes a race condition from "modifying the bitmap data while you are in the middle of reading it" to "making modifications to the wrong bitmap"

Comment: Do you know if there's any way/tip to reduce the size of bitmaps stored in the memory?

Comment: @Ruan the only way I know of is to create a new bitmap that has lower dimensions/color depth, or enables compression, etc and then copy the pixels from the old bitmap to the new bitmap. Or, simply don't use bitmaps at all, use a smaller format instead, like JPG/GIF/etc.